# Why my domain redirect on Google Apps is returning 404?

Tags: redirects, google-workspace

I have a configuration in the [Google Apps Control Panel](https://dcc.securepaynet.net/default.aspx?prog_id=412956&domain=tombrito.com&user=54277214#) (dcc.securepaynet.net) to redirect [tombrito.com](http://tombrito.com) to http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4499244H9.

It worked fine until some days ago, but now it's returning 404.

If you access [tombrito.com](http://tombrito.com) you can see the favicon in the title of the browser tab, but the page shows a 404 error. The target page http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?id=K4499244H9 is fine, it's only some problem with my redirect.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you say Google Apps when dcc.securepaynet.net is a GoDaddy site?  Did you mean GoDaddy apps?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I bought from the Google Apps website while I was registering, so I say Google Apps, but I don't really know who is taking care of which part.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review my answer?  How do you administer the domain tombrito.com?  Can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have a DNS issue with `tombrito.com`.

Doing a DNS lookup for tombrito.com using `dig` shows that four IP addresses are returned.

Using `curl` to send requests for `tombrito.com` to all four IP addresses shows that only IP address `64.202.189.170` returns the 301 redirect you expect.  The three other IP addresses (`216.239.32.21`, `216.239.34.21` and `216.239.36.21`) all return a 404 not found error.

```
;tombrito.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tombrito.com.           3371    IN      A       216.239.36.21
tombrito.com.           3371    IN      A       64.202.189.170
tombrito.com.           3371    IN      A       216.239.34.21
tombrito.com.           3371    IN      A       216.239.32.21

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tombrito.com.           3371    IN      NS      ns12.domaincontrol.com.
tombrito.com.           3371    IN      NS      ns11.domaincontrol.com.
```

I recommend that you update your DNS for tombrito.com to only return IP address `64.202.189.170` or get the web servers on the other 3 IP addresses to perform the redirect.

Here are the `curl` commands that I used to individually query each IP address:

```
curl --verbose --header "Host: tombrito.com" http://216.39.32.21
.
.
curl --verbose --header "Host: tombrito.com" http://64.202.189.170
```

I hope that this information helps.

**Update:**

Is this what you see when you view your Control Panel?  If it is, do you see more than one IP address for the "@" record?

[image]

Comment: The sad part: looks like the only options in the interface of the DNS configuration is to make or delete the forward... I can try remove and remake the forward, but again, it's sad that it just stop working without I make any change.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer.  I posted a screenshot of what I see for my domain.  I suspect that you have multiple "A" records for "@".  You can delete the extra ones if you click on "Launch".

Comment: Today it's working again, without I make any change... Maybe it was a temporary Google or GoDaddy problem. I'll wait to see if it will continue to work. By the way, this is not the inteface I see, it's a very simplier one with a table [Domain Name | Expires | Status | Features].

Comment: I still see 4 IP addresses being returned for `tombrito.com`, I suspect that you received the right IP address and now your local system has that address cached.  What IP address do you get if you ping tombrito.com?

Comment: I get 64.202.189.170, with no answer for the ping. By the way, I just realized it's redirecting correctly only in my home pc. If I open an anonymous tab, it will return 404. I think you're right about the cache.

Comment: Hey! I just found the page equal to your screenshot, and yes, I see 3 IP records with the DSN "A" and Manager "@". I'll try to fix it here...

Comment: Yes, the fix was just removing the additional A records, thanks!

Comment: Now I'm with this related problem (now with sub-domain, and no duplicates in the DNS Manager) http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38664/why-my-sub-domain-redirect-returns-a-blank-page