# Why my sub-domain redirect returns a blank page?

Tags: godaddy, domain-forwarding

I have the domain http://dropbox.tombrito.com/ (on GoDaddy) forwarding with masking to [www.dropbox.com/sh/k6ypvx4y4kf0gu6/rdjxQ1b1OL](http://www.dropbox.com/sh/k6ypvx4y4kf0gu6/rdjxQ1b1OL)

It was working fine some time ago, but now the result is a blank page (although the Dropbox's favicon appears correctly in the browser's tab title).

The DNS manager shows me a single entry with the name "dropbox":

```
 A  dropbox 64.202.189.170
```

Any idea what's wrong?

**Related:** [Why my domain redirect on Google Apps is returning 404?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36390/why-my-domain-redirect-on-google-apps-is-returning-404)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Masked forwarding uses frames to display the site being redirected to.  For dropbox that does not appear to work.  You may want to use use a regular redirect instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>dropbox.tombrito.com</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.dropbox.com/sh/k6ypvx4y4kf0gu6/rdjxQ1b1OL" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 06 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

Comment: The masked forwarding worked for some months. Maybe something changed in the Dropbox website? Not sure. Anyway, thanks for the workaround!

Comment: HeatfanJohn is correct dropbox is now sending the X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN header which will prevent most modern browsers from loading the page inside of GoDaddy's iframe. Try a changing dropbox.tombrito.com to a cname record pointing at dropbox.

Comment: Forget the cname part of my comment.  A full redirect is really you're only option at this point, short of integrating with the Dropbox API and building your own page to display available links.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome's Inspector you get this error

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Two ways that should fix it:

1. IFRAMES - [Custom Domain Dropbox](http://www.techairlines.com/2010/11/28/custom-domain-dropbox/)
2. Add some PHP - [Overcoming “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

   `<?php header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); ?>`